# How do i replace all items in an array with that of another

Tags: c#

```
str = str.Replace(letters[0], encryptedcharacters[0]);
```

Hi everyone above you can see I am using the replace method to replace items in the string array letters, with the string array encrypted characters. They both have the same amount of items, which is 26, is there a way to do this, without copying this line of code 26 times?

Comment: why cant you write it in loop? for(int i=0;i <26;i++) {your code}. Complier will do it for you

Comment: how about a for loop form 0 to 25?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop ?

```
   for(int i = 0;i < letters.Length; ++i)
      str = str.Replace(letters[i], encryptedcharacters[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot better sense

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
encryptedcharacters.CopyTo(letters, 0);
```